# How do I read this XML correctly?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to read this XML:

```
<item_proto extended="true" version="1">
    <Item vnum="1" name="'y'" gb2312name="Treasure" type="9" subtype="0" weight="0" size="1" antiflag="0" flag="0" wearflag="0" immuneflag="0" gold="0" buy_price="0" limittype0="0" limitvalue0="0" limittype1="0" limitvalue1="0" applytype0="0" applyvalue0="0" applytype1="0" applyvalue1="0" applytype2="0" applyvalue2="0" value0="0" value1="0" value2="0" value3="0" value4="0" value5="0" socket0="0" socket1="0" socket2="0" socket3="0" socket4="0" socket5="0" refine_vnum="11" refine_set="11" magic_pct="0" specular="0" socket_pct="0" />
    <Item vnum="2" name="'l'" gb2312name="Key" type="0" subtype="0" weight="0" size="1" antiflag="0" flag="0" wearflag="0" immuneflag="0" gold="0" buy_price="0" limittype0="0" limitvalue0="0" limittype1="0" limitvalue1="0" applytype0="0" applyvalue0="0" applytype1="0" applyvalue1="0" applytype2="0" applyvalue2="0" value0="0" value1="0" value2="0" value3="0" value4="0" value5="0" socket0="0" socket1="0" socket2="0" socket3="0" socket4="0" socket5="0" refine_vnum="11" refine_set="11" magic_pct="0" specular="0" socket_pct="0" />
    <Item vnum="19" name="'e9'" gb2312name="Sword" type="1" subtype="0" weight="0" size="2" antiflag="32" flag="1" wearflag="16" immuneflag="0" gold="100" buy_price="750" limittype0="1" limitvalue0="0" limittype1="0" limitvalue1="0" applytype0="7" applyvalue0="22" applytype1="0" applyvalue1="0" applytype2="0" applyvalue2="0" value0="0" value1="15" value2="19" value3="13" value4="15" value5="63" socket0="0" socket1="64992" socket2="127" socket3="64976" socket4="21631" socket5="4855" refine_vnum="0" refine_set="0" magic_pct="15" specular="100" socket_pct="1" />
</item_proto>
```

If possible, I want to read just one of the nodes: `gb2312name`.

Here’s what I tried:

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument() 
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Item").Item(3) 

'Display the contents of the child nodes. 
If root.HasChildNodes Then 
    Dim i As Integer 

    For i = 0 To root.ChildNodes.Count - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(root.ChildNodes(i).InnerText) 
    Next i 
End If
```

Comment: @MiguelSilva Start with the official docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20esef39.aspx) and come back saying what you tried and **how** it didn't work. Meaning: show us code (edited into your question, properly formatted) and error messages (ditto). Also provide some example output given your sample input - as in, the data structure that will be the result of whatever function you're writing.

Comment: @MiguelSilva you mention you want to get 1 node `gb2312name`.  You have 3 `Attributes` with that name.  Do you want to get a collection with all 3 attribute values?

Comment: You mentioned that this code gives you an exception. Which exception?

Comment: You have to load the XML file into the `XMLDocument` before you can start reading it. Your code just declares a variable. Also, `gb2312name` is an `attribute`, not a `node`.

Comment: If by `.Item(3)` you meant the last Item node, shouldn't that be `.Item(2)`? (zero-index collections).  Also, `root`, if it's one of the Item tags, doesn't have any child nodes so you will never enter that block of code.

Comment: If you did load the XML, the problem is that you’re using `InnerText` (should be `NodeValue` anyways) and not `Attributes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s start with the probable exception-causing problem: (most) collections’ indices start at zero, this one included. So if you want to get the third `<Item>`, it’s `.Item(2)` (or just `(2)`):

```vb
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Item")(2)
```

Next, `root.ChildNodes` doesn’t include attributes, and even if it did, `InnerText` wouldn’t be the right property to check. Luckily, [`Attributes` exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx) and you don’t even need a loop! (If you did, it would be a `For Each` loop, by the way.)

```vb
ListBox1.Items.Add(root.Attributes("gb2312name"))
```

So if you wanted to add `gb2312name` from each element, it would be:

```vb
For Each el In doc.GetElementsByTagName("Item")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(el.Attributes("gb2312name"))
Next
```